# Trying to login to a website in iOS app, no JSON response

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I'm trying to login to a website and get a response using JSON using this code:

```
@try {

    if([[txtUsername text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[txtPassword text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
        [self alertStatus:@"Please enter both Username and Password" :@"Login Failed!"];
    } else {
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"username=%@&password=%@",[txtUsername text],[txtPassword text]];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://yedion.afeka.ac.il/yedion/fireflyweb.aspx?prgname=login"];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        [NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
        if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

            SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
            NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
            NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
            NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
            NSLog(@"%d",success);
            if(success == 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                [self alertStatus:@"Logged in Successfully." :@"Login Success!"];

            } else {

                NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"error_message"];
                [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Login Failed!"];
            }

        } else {
            if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Login Failed!"];
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    [self alertStatus:@"Login Failed." :@"Login Failed!"];
}
```

In the log I can see there is no JSON response so I can't know if the login was successful or not. 
Is there any other way to login to this website and get a response wether or not it was successful?

Thanks!

Comment: How is this related to Xcode?

Comment: Because I'm creating a login screen in Xcode for iOS app.

Comment: No. This is not related to Xcode. Xcode is just an IDE and it doesn't have anything to do with general iOS-programming questions. Please read its tag wiki for further information.

Comment: You're also using a Mac to do so, that would not be a good reason for using the tag `OSX`.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems ok to me but do check the web service and also check that you give correct keywords for json if the key given to the objectForKey and your key in web service are different you will never get a json response.

Answer (score 0):

Use Get method and try

```
[ request setHTTPMethod:@"GET" ];
```